# When did "ain't" become slang?

Tags: history, formality, contractions, register, is-it-a-rule

In Anthony Trollope's *The Way We Live Now*, there are several places where "ain't" is used instead of "am not", such as:

> "I ain't afraid of him, if you mean that," continued Lord Nidderdale.

— Anthony Trollope, *The Way We Live Now* (Kindle Locations 3161-3162).

> "But then she don't want me, and I ain't quite sure that I want her."

— Anthony Trollope, *The Way We Live Now* (Kindle Locations 3165-3166).

Besides Lord Nidderdale, who belongs to the aristocracy, elsewhere in the book it is the village girl Ruby and other village residents who use "ain't" in the sense of "is not", "are not" and "am not".

Is the fact that today "ain't" is regarded as slang a development post-Trollope (who was writing not so long ago), or is His Lordship merely being colloquial? Was Trollope actually a catalyst in this change?

Comment: _Ain’t_ isn’t slang at all—it’s just a colloquial contraction, like _isn’t_ or _haven’t_. It’s lower in register than both those two, and it’s the butt of far more stigmatisation; but slang is a different thing altogether. When _ain’t_ went from being just any old colloquial contraction to being a specifically lower-register colloquial contraction is a good question, though. Something tells me we’re looking at the 19th century, but I have a hunch it probably happened at different times in different places and dialects.

Comment: I'm no authority, but my sense is that it is Cockney and will have appeared in Dickens' dialogue.

Comment: There is a comprehensive Wiki article on *aint*. It confirms my suspicion about Dickens' use. *An't with a long "a" sound began to be written as ain't, which first appears in writing in 1749. By the time ain't appeared, an't was already being used for am not, are not, and is not. An't and ain't coexisted as written forms well into the nineteenth century—Charles Dickens used the terms interchangeably... e.g. Little Dorrit (1857): "'I guessed it was you, Mr Pancks," said she, 'for it's quite your regular night; ain't it? ... An't it gratifying, Mr Pancks, though; really?'".

Comment: [Slang](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slang) is “very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language”. *Ain't* is the exact opposite of that, on all accounts. It is as ordinary, ubiquitous, unmetaphorical and universally understood as you could possibly get. You might as well ask when "the" became slang.

Comment: Basically, the lower classes decided to regularize the negative in all persons, so _ain't_ went from being the contraction of _am not_  to being thought "lower class". This is what always happens when people regularize language -- the regular form becomes infra dig. Note that English deprived itself of a contraction for _am not_ to satisfy this class battle. Now we can't say _I ain't interested_ without being taken for an illiterate -- instead of a language reformer.

Comment: From a purely grammatical perspective, it's difficult to understand why ain't should be vilified when an equally objectionable usage, aren't (in such situations as: "I'm taller than you, aren't I?"), is not. (I describe it as 'objectionable' purely because the verb does not agree in number with the subject, not because I personally have anything against it [I don't]).

Comment: @RegDwigнt: It's the opposite of that on *most* counts, but I think it satisfies the "very informal usage" part, and that is presumably what the OP means by it . . .

Comment: @ruakh *Slang* does not mean a taboo word that marks you as a bumpkin, something that you do not say in polite company. I keep seeing NNS use it that way, and I want to know who is filling their heads with such anti-linguistic tripe.

Comment: @ErikKowal: I've read that *aren't* and *ain't* are actually etymological doublets, both being variants of *an't*, with the <r> originally being strictly orthographic in non-rhotic dialects. (I'm not sure how much to credit that explanation, though, seeing as *aren't* is currently found with a real R sound in various rhotic dialects.)

Comment: @tchrist: If "NNS" means "non-native speaker", then I don't think it's a native vs. non-native thing, but rather a linguist vs. non-linguist thing. I could be wrong, but I suspect that most native speakers would accept a statement that *ain't* is "slang".

Comment: @tchrist: Well, most self-described linguists are descriptivists, who hopefully (and frequently) have better sense than to describe lay usages as "foggy-headed" and "floozy talk" . . .

Comment: @tchrist: "Slang", like many terms, has multiple senses. I'm sorry that this bothers you so much; you have my pity. (But, only a little bit. I'd feel more sympathy if you had at least bothered to edit the question to conform to your terminological preferences, rather than merely posting comments assailing the intelligence of anyone who does not share them.)

Comment: @ruakh: Speaking as an admitted linguist, self- and other-described, I object to the term "descriptivist". I am not one. Nobody is one. "Descriptivist" is a straw man made up by peevers to vilify. Using "descriptivist" -- or worse, attributing it to somebody without their permission -- is just name-calling. In reality there are only linguists (a group which includes all grammarians) and peevers. "Slang", btw, is not a term with an exact definition; normally it means 'something I don't like".

Comment: It is interesting to know Anthony Trollope moved to and live in Ireland where the dialect 'amn't' is used. To say 'amn't' they drop 'm' and pronounce like ain't. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Trollope

Answer (score 10):

According to the following sources:

[Ain't](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ain%27t&searchmode=none) was originally  the proper contraction for *am not*. The contraction  became  popular as a generic one in the 19th century and started to be considered nonstandard ( not slang) English since then:

> - *1706, originally a contraction of am not, and in proper use with that sense* until it began to be used as a generic contraction for are not, is not, etc., **in early 19c. Cockney dialect of London; popularized by representations of this in Dickens, etc., which led to the word being banished from correct English.**

Source: Etymonline

[Ain't](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/10/is-aint-misbehaving.html):

> - Historically, “ain’t” appears to have evolved in the late 1700s from an earlier > - form, “an’t,” which was first recorded in the late 1600s but was probably common in speech early in that century. So let’s start with the earlier form.
> - “An’t” was originally a contraction of “am not” (as in “I an’t going”) and “are not” (as in “you an’t” or “we an’t” or “they an’t”). The earliest published citations are 1695 (for “an’t” = “am not”) and 1696 (for “an’t” = “are not”).
> - But as early as 1710, “an’t” was also being used in place of “isn’t” as a contraction for “is not,” as in “that an’t fair,” or “he an’t here.”
>
>   - These citations come from Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage, and are earlier than those in the Oxford English Dictionary.
>   - As for correctness, the OED labels “an’t” = “are not” simply as a contraction (presumably as correct as, say, “isn’t” or “don’t”). But it labels “an’t” = “am not” as a colloquial usage; that is to say, it was somewhat less correct. And finally the OED labels “an’t” = “is not” as an illiterate usage.
> - Thus, so far we have (1) the legitimate “an’t” – a contraction of “are not”; (2) the colloquial “an’t” – a contraction of “am not”; and (3) the illiterate “an’t” – a contraction for “is not.”
> - Strictly speaking, by the way, the contraction for “am not” should be “a’n’t” or “amn’t,” and in fact people once used “amn’t”; they still do in Irish English and Scots English.
> - Meanwhile, in the late 1700s people began spelling “an’t” as “ain’t,” which may have been closer to the way it was pronounced at the time. (A common pronunciation of “are,” for example, was “air.”) **Before long, “ain’t” became the usual spelling, and by the late 1800s, “an’t” had disappeared. What disappeared along with it were any claims that “ain’t” may have had to being a legitimate contraction.**
> - Keep in mind that “an’t” came along at a time when a large family of English contractions was being formed: words like “don’t,” “won’t,” “can’t,” “isn’t,” and many more that we now consider standard English.
> - “An’t” (and later “ain’t”) **was just one of the crowd for many years, and was used by the upper classes as well as the lower, educated and otherwise. You see it in a lot of late 18th-century and early 19th-century English novels in the mouths of ladies and gentlemen.**
> - But “ain’t” was different from the rest, and in the 19th century, criticisms arose. The other contractions seemed to have a clearly traceable parentage, while “ain’t” was all over the place. It just wasn’t as clear in its derivation as a word like “don’t” (do not), or “can’t” (cannot), or “won’t” (will not).
> - And to complicate the picture even further, uses of “ain’t” started multiplying, so that it was used as a contraction of “has not” (as in “he ain’t been here”) and “have not” (as in “we ain’t seen him”). Chaos!
> - **For all these reasons, since the 19th century “ain’t” hasn’t been considered a legitimate contraction and is still described in dictionaries as “nonstandard.”** But it does live on, and probably always will. When educated people use it now, though, they probably intend a kind of reverse snobbery or are trying for a humorous effect.

Source: www.grammarphobia.com

Comment: In England of the 18th century, and into the early 19th, the gentry classes spoke their local dialect. When William Gladstone, the son of a Liverpool Merchant first went to Eton, he spoke with a Liverpool accent. The Received Pronunciation as we know it today evolved as a way of speaking by the fashionable classes in the 19th century, together with other mores which characterise the English bourgeoisie.